# HTML5 Responsive upon canvas resize

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Facing a problem with responsiveness when triggering media query for mobile.
The canvas just vanishes.

Issue:

When resizing to mobile, the aqua canvas just vanishes.

One of the solution:

To hard code the div `<canvas id="main" width="1024" height="640"></canvas>`

JSBIN:
http://jsbin.com/poposopahi/edit?html,css,output

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Global Styles */

body {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 92%;
 max-width: 960px;
 padding-left: 2.275%;
 padding-right: 2.275%;
}
/* Header */
header {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
 background-color: white;
 color:black;
 width: 300px;
 text-align: center;
}
header .logoPlaceholder span {
 width: 180px;
 height: 22px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: black;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 53px;
}
header .logoPlaceholder2 span {
 width: 180px;
 height: 22px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: black;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 53px;
}
header .profilePhoto {
 background-color: rgba(237,237,237,1.00);
 width: 259px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 259px;
 clear: both;
}
header .profileHeader h1 {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 24px;
}
header .profileHeader h3 {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 24px;
}
hr {
 background-color: rgba(208,207,207,1.00);
 height: 1px;
}
header .profileHeader p {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.8;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 60px;
 clear: both;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
 border-radius: 50%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav img:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Media query for Mobile devices*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 285px) and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Header */
header {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
}
.wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
} 
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: left;
}
header .profilePhoto {
 display: inline-block;
}
header .profileHeader {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10%;
}
header .profileHeader p {
 text-align: justify;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 60px;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 15%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 23px;
}

}

/* Media Query for Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Header */
header {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
}
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
header .profilePhoto {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 margin-right: 3%;
 margin-top: 5%;
}
header .profileHeader {
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 7%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
 width: 74px;
 height: 74px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 23px;
}

}

/* Desktops and laptops  */
@media only screen and (min-width:1025px) {
/* Header */
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
header .profilePhoto {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 margin-right: 3%;
}
header .profileHeader {
 text-align: left;
 padding-top: 10%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
 width: 74px;
 height: 74px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 23px;
}


 
.wrapper {
   display: table;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.container {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.canvas-container {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 1024px;
   min-width: 120px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#main {
   width: auto;
   background-color: aqua;
} 
 
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>About Page template By Adobe Dreamweaver CC</title>
<link href="AboutPageAssets/styles/aboutPageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/montserrat:n4:default;source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Header content -->
<header>
  <div class="profileLogo"> 
    <!-- Profile logo. Add a img tag in place of <span>. -->
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Name :</span></p>
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Attempts :</span></p>
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Score :</span></p>
  </div>
  <section>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="main" width="1024" height="640"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>
  <!-- Links to Social network accounts -->
  <aside class="socialNetworkNavBar">
    <div class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <img src="AboutPageAssets/images/social.png" alt="sample"> </div>
    <div class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <img src="AboutPageAssets/images/social.png"  alt="sample"> </div>
    <div class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <img src="AboutPageAssets/images/social.png"  alt="sample"> </div>
   
  </aside>
</header>
<!-- content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the CSS styles for main id

```
#main {
    width: auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

in the media query

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:1025px) {  
     ...
 }
```

only. Put it under

```
 /* Global Styles */
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tnLy9ab6/

Comment: thanks for pointing my small error , i forgotten the bracket has been closed.